# Embedded Google Earth not retrieving photos from KMZ url

Tags: google-earth, photos, kmz

I am using a gadget to embed Google Earth on my page and display a series of points and photos stored in a KMZ. I have uploaded my KMZ to my hosting account file manager and added the KMZ's url to the code:

```
<script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://dl.google.com/developers/maps/embedkmlgadget.xml&amp;up_kml_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebmapacademy.com%2Fkmls%2FCO_bcE6_Grizzly_Ridge_GeoChange_1955-2011.kmz&amp;up_view_mode=earth&amp;up_earth_2d_fallback=0&amp;up_earth_fly_from_space=1&amp;up_earth_show_nav_controls=1&amp;up_earth_show_buildings=0&amp;up_earth_show_terrain=1&amp;up_earth_show_roads=1&amp;up_earth_show_borders=1&amp;up_earth_sphere=earth&amp;up_maps_zoom_out=0&amp;up_maps_default_type=map&amp;synd=open&amp;w=500&amp;h=400&amp;title=Embedded+KML+Viewer&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

The fly in works (although it is sloooow to zoom), the pins load, but--nstead of photos in the pop up--the pin displays "schema0:Photos".

How can I get the photos to display?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess one way to solve a problem is to force yourself to properly formulate the question.

I got it to work!

Unzip the KMZ and ftp photos to your server to get individual urls for each file. Then edit the KML so the photo paths point to their respective urls. Upload your edited KML to the folder with the images, and paste the url of the KML into the gadget that generates the GE code. Yay!

Couple extra things:

## - So when the photos were named “Image” they were displayed, however when were named photos “Placemark” and Google Earth was like, yeaaah, no dice. Renaming the photos did the trick.

## 2 – Careful! There’s also a “tour” gadget – so if you have a KMZ tour great, if not your fly-in won’t work.

## 3 – This is weird and I can’t explain it, but when you go back into edit your gadget code after your page has been published, it has a knack for disappearing. Simple solution, publish it and leave it alone, and if you do update obviously the next simple solution is to just go back to the gadget and get the code again. Just annoying really - anyone know anything about this?!?

## 4 – If you didn’t do your due diligence in naming your placemarks in the field, you can edit them in Notepad++ by simply changing the “” to “” or whatever you want to name it.